# java.util.NoSuchElementException even though input file has data

Tags: java

I have written this code to find out an output and i am running this using Runtime in a servlet. It shows java.util.NoSuchElementEception even though i have checked that input file has some data:

```
public class Sec1q10 {

static int fact(int n) {
    int p = 1;
    if (n != 1) {
        p = n * fact(n - 1);
    }
    return p;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        System.out.println("first");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("F:/sem5/algorithm/in.txt"));
        String no = in.next();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(no);
        System.out.println(n);
        int s = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            s += fact(n);
            n--;
        }
        System.out.println("sum=" + s);
        String s1 = "" + s + "here";

        PrintWriter out;
        System.out.println(s1);
        out = new PrintWriter("F:/sem5/algorithm/out.txt");

        out.write(s1);
        System.out.println(s1);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
    }

}
}
```

I even run this on cmd where it is showing the output without any exception but not writing anything in the file  F:/sem5/algorithm/out.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see results in output file close `PrintWriter` after writing in it

```
    PrintWriter out;
    System.out.println(s1);
    out = new PrintWriter("F:/sem5/algorithm/out.txt");
    try
    {
       out.write(s1);
       System.out.println(s1);
    }
    finally
    {
       out.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the `Scanner` class you should actually test to ensure input is waiting for you before trying to read it using the `hasNextXXXXX()` methods.

try this:

```
String no; 

while(in.hasNext())
{
    no = in.next();

    //.....
}
```

the problem isn't that your input file doesn't have any data, it's that your input file runs out of data because you continually read. If you try to read when nothing is there you will get a `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: I even tried that..in this case also same thing happens..while using runtime ..the if loop is not executed but is executed in the cmd..

Comment: @user182022 Well if you are only reading the first thing, just change the `while` above to `if`.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is that the Directory does not exist. Are you sure it does? If not, you should either make it manually, or use the `.mkdir()` function